# How to parse nested json with FutureProvider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to parse a nested JSON document in my app. The JSON structure looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "This is a Text1"
        },
        {
            "type": "latex",
            "value": "\frac00"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "This is a Text2"
        },
        {
            "type": "latex",
            "value": "\frac00"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "This is a Text3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "This is a Text"
        }
    ]
}
```

]
And here are my model classes:

```
class Tutorial {
  String id;
  List<Content> content;

  Tutorial({this.id, this.content});

  Tutorial.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    if (json['content'] != null) {
      content = new List<Content>();
      json['content'].forEach((v) {
        content.add(new Content.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    if (this.content != null) {
      data['content'] = this.content.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Content {
  String type;
  String value;

  Content({this.type, this.value});

  Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = json['type'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is how I retrieve that Json and make the response object:

```
import 'package:Mathzi/pages/courses/models/tutorialModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class TutorialService {
  Future<List> fetchTutorial() async {
    var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/tutorial.json');
    final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response) as List;
    return jsonResponse.map((tutorial) => Tutorial.fromJson(tutorial)).toList();
  }
}
```

And here are my Screen Widget tree:

```
  final TutorialService tutorialService = TutorialService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider(
      create: (context) => tutorialService.fetchTutorial(),
      catchError: (context, error) => print(error.toString()),
      child: SizeTransition(
        axis: Axis.vertical,
        sizeFactor: animation,
        child: GestureDetector(
          //behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: TutParagraph()
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And my TutParagraph.dart:

```
import 'package:Mathzi/pages/courses/models/tutorialModel.dart';
import 'package:catex/catex.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'models/tutorialModel.dart';

class TutParagraph extends StatelessWidget {
  const TutParagraph({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Content> parag = Provider.of<List<Content>>(context);
    return (parag == null)
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: parag.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (parag[index].type.toString() == "text")
                return Text(parag[index].value.toString());
              else if (parag[index].type.toString() == "latex")
                return CaTeX(parag[index].value.toString());
              else
                return null;
            },
          );
  }
}
```

if the type is equal to *text* I use a `Text()` widget to display it and if it is *latex* I use `CaTex()`

When I run my code it gives me this error message:

Error:

> Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this
> TutParagraph Widget
>
> To fix, please:
>
> - Ensure the Provider<List> is an ancestor to this
>   TutParagraph Widget   * Provide types to Provider<List>   *
>   Provide types to Consumer<List>   * Provide types to
>   Provider.of<List>()   * Ensure the correct `context` is being
>   used.

Comment: Try to give the type to the `FutureProvider<List>`, also I don't see a Provider of type `<List<Content>>`

Comment: @EdwynZN My json response is alredy a List. here:     return jsonResponse.map((tutorial) => Tutorial.fromJson(tutorial)).toList();
and here is my Content<List> which is a nested List in Tutorial<List>
    List<Content> parag = Provider.of<List<Content>>(context);

Comment: Yeah I see that, but provider only see a List, doesn't know there is a nested one of type Content inside each element of that list so you can't call it like that, `List parag = Provider.of<List>(context);` will give you no error because that's the proper type of List you're returning from the future

Comment: Now it gives this error: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<dynamic>> above this TutParagraph Widget

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to try to cast and explicitly tell the type of object the List uses to avoid this sort of problems instead of let it infere it

```
class TutorialService {
  Future<List<Tutorial>> fetchTutorial() async {  //Tell the trturn type of the List
    var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/tutorial.json');
    final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response) as List;
    return jsonResponse.map<Tutorial>((tutorial) => Tutorial.fromJson(tutorial)).toList();
    //Cast the type in the map method <Tutorial>
  }
}
```

Again in the FutureProvider

```
FutureProvider<List<Tutorial>>( //perhaps it can infere it correctly now that the return type explicitly says is a List<Tutorial>, but lets add it anyway just in case
   create: (context) => tutorialService.fetchTutorial(),
   catchError: (context, error) => print(error.toString()),
   child: ...
)
```

And in TutParagraph

```
class TutParagraph extends StatelessWidget {
  const TutParagraph({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Tutorial> tutorial = Provider.of<List<Tutorial>>(context); //it should find the FutureProvider
    List<Content> parag = (tutorial?.isEmpty ?? true) ? null : tutorial[0].content; //but this will only give you the list of the first element of the tutorial List
    return (parag == null)
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: parag.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (parag[index].type.toString() == "text")
                return Text(parag[index].value.toString());
              else if (parag[index].type.toString() == "latex")
                return CaTeX(parag[index].value.toString());
              else
                return null;
            },
          );
  }
}
```

Now if you want to retrieve only a `List<Content>` you should try to change the logic of `tutorialService.fetchTutorial()` to return only that type of list, because the Provider doesn't know what types are inside of Tutorial and obviously if you have a `List<Tutorial>` it doesn't know the `List<Content>` of what index of the list of Tutorial you really want

Comment: Now, it gives this error: (dirty,
dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<List<Tutorial>>]):
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: '_get'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  TutParagraph
  file:///Users/amin/FlutterProjects/mathzi/lib/pages/courses/tutoria
  l_page.dart:267:22

Comment: That's because the list is not retrieved yet (Future hasn't ended) so it's null, try checking for a mill value before try to use it